Sum two raster stack together ignoring NAs
I have 2 rasters with multiple layers that I want to sum together.  Both raster have the same number of layers, and I want to sum all the layer from one raster to their respective layers in the second raster.
Here are example rasters:
library(terra)

set.seed(123)
r1 <- c(rast(matrix(sample(1:10, 100, replace=T), nrow=10, ncol=10)),
        rast(matrix(sample(1:10, 100, replace=T), nrow=10, ncol=10)),
        rast(matrix(sample(1:10, 100, replace=T), nrow=10, ncol=10))
)

r2 <- c(rast(matrix(sample(1:10, 100, replace=T), nrow=10, ncol=10)),
        rast(matrix(sample(1:10, 100, replace=T), nrow=10, ncol=10)),
        rast(matrix(sample(1:10, 100, replace=T), nrow=10, ncol=10))
)
        
r1[sample(1:100, 20)] <- NA
r2[sample(1:100, 20)] <- NA

This is super easy with raster calculation:
r_tot <- r1+r2

But I don't have the option na.rm=T if I sum it that way.  In my case, I need to ignore NA all together.
Functions like calc, sum, and app works on all layers of a single raster.  I couldn't find a simple way of adding up two rasters while ignoring the NAs. Is there an easy way to do this without having to split my raster and run each layer individually?
I though of converting NAs to 0 and make the sum then, but this is not ideal as I would have to find way to distinguish real 0 to real NA in the final raster.

You might be interested in app() after all, using a SpatRasterDataset object as input.
According to ?app:

You can also apply a function fun across datasets by layer of a SpatRasterDataset. In that case, summarization is by layer across SpatRasters.

This is how the result would look like using your data:
x <- sds(r1, r2)

r <- app(x, fun = "sum", na.rm = TRUE)
plot(r)


Created on 2024-05-06 with reprex v2.1.0
